# SOLR - adding words/queries to the synonyms.txt based on query texts added from elevate.xml

Tags: tomcat, solr

Does anybody know if theres a way to get the query text from elevate.xml to work for synonyms.txt

example:

```
<!--elevate.xml -->
<query text="cat”>
  <doc id="4nx677/node/4090" />
</query>

<!--synonyms.txt -->
cat, dog, sheep
```

i've also tried:

```
dog => cat
```

I tried the above and the dog and sheep don't show the same results as cat after its been elevated

for dog and sheep it only shows the results from cat before it was added to elevate.xml

Comment: Have you tried using the `queryFieldType` to tell elevate to analyze the incoming text with the field you have synonyms defined for?

Comment: See [the documentation for `queryFieldType`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-query-elevation-component.html#TheQueryElevationComponent-ConfiguringtheQueryElevationComponent).

Comment: excellent, thanks @MatsLindh

Comment: Did it work? I'll add it as the answer in that case.

Comment: sorry it didn't work.. the thing is the synonyms works but only for text that hasn't been added to the elevate.xml.. do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Does the field type expand synonyms at query time? Otherwise you might need a second field that you just use for processing the query string before elevating